# Mostrar un contenido dependiendo de la URL

Tags: javascript, error404

Estoy creando una página de error que funcione en 2 idiomas. La idea, es que por defecto muestre un `<div="404-spanish">` con una URL del tipo: [www.jonathancenteno.com/estapaginanoexiste](http://www.jonathancenteno.com/estapaginanoexiste). Sin embargo, cuando en la URL aparezca /en/, la idea sería que el `<div="404-spanish">` dejara de mostrarse y mostrara el `<div="404-english">` en una URL del tipo: [www.jonathancenteno.com/en/estapaginanoexiste](http://www.jonathancenteno.com/estapaginanoexiste).

Gracias de antemano.

EDITADO:

He probado los siguientes códigos y ninguno me funciona. Aunque tampoco sé si son correctos:

HTML:

```
<div id="404-page"></div>
<div id="404-spanish"></div>
<div id="404-english"></div>
```

SCRIPT

Opción 1:

```
<script>
var win = window.location;

var webPath = win.pathname;

var parent = document.getElementById("404-page");

var child = document.getElementById("404-spanish");

var y = document.getElementById("404-english");


//Dividimos la string en un array
var splittedPath = webPath.split("/");

//El primer valor del array segun la estructura mostrada sería el del idioma
switch(splittedPath[0]) {
  case "en": 
    parent.replaceChild(y, child);
    break;

  default:

    break;
}
</script>
```

Opción 2:

```
 <script>
    var win = window.location;

    var webPath = win.pathname;

    var x = document.getElementById("404-spanish");

    var y = document.getElementById("404-english");


    //Dividimos la string en un array
    var splittedPath = webPath.split("/");

    //El primer valor del array segun la estructura mostrada sería el del idioma
    switch(splittedPath[0]) {
      case "en": 
        x.style.display = "none";
        y.style.display = "block";
        break;

      default:
       y.style.display = "none";
      break;
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Bienvenido..Jonathan Centeno., te saludamos y te damos la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, por lo tanto **te sugiero modificar tu pregunta, agregar lo que has realizado, más información, etc**, saludos!

Comment: Comparte el código que estas utilizando para ayudarte de una mejor manera.

Comment: ¿La segunda opción no cambia los estilos o te muestra algún error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He probado el código que te ha dicho alex que es el que has puesto en tu segunda opción y creo que el problema que tiene ese código es que la posición 0 de splittedPath está vacía, en las dos pruebas que he hecho me he dado cuenta de que para acceder a la primera opción hay poner 1 y no 0. He puesto tu ejemplo cambiando el 0 por 1 y he añadido algunas alertas para que veas la diferencia, la primera alerta muestra el webPath completo (/js), la segunda el elemento 0 del patrón (no muestra nada) y la tercera el elemnto 1 (js).

```js
var win = window.location;

    var webPath = win.pathname;

    alert(webPath);

    var x = document.getElementById("404-spanish");

    var y = document.getElementById("404-english");


    //Dividimos la string en un array
    var splittedPath = webPath.split("/");
    
    alert(splittedPath[0]);
    alert(splittedPath[1]);


    //El primer valor del array segun la estructura mostrada sería el del idioma
    switch(splittedPath[1]) {
      case "js": 
        x.style.display = "none"
        y.style.display = "block"
        break;
      default:
       y.style.display = "none"
      break;
    }
```

```css
.x {width:200px;height:200px;background:Red;}
.y {width:200px;height:200px;background:blue;display:none;}
```

```html
<div id="404-page"></div>
<div class="x" id="404-spanish"></div>
<div class="y" id="404-english"></div>
```

Comment: Cierto. Lo acabo de probar y funciona. Cuando lo probé antes con el código bien escrito, siempre me salia el resultado por defecto. Ahora todo tiene mucho más sentido. Muchas gracias a ti y a @alex55132

Comment: De nada, un placer haberte servido de ayuda, cuando puedas marca alguna respuesta como correcta para que esta pregunta sea considerada solucionada. Esta respuesta o la de alex, la que consideres tú, pero lo importante es que aceptes alguna respuesta si ya has solucionado tu problema para que no haya más actividad aquí.

Comment: Listo. Pensaba que se marcaba sola con darle positivo. He marcado la tuya pues el código esta completo y es correcto. Un saludo y gracias de nuevo.

Answer (score 1):

Supongamos que tenemos la siguiente url:

> www.jonathancenteno.com/en/estapaginanoexiste

Para obtener el idioma que quiere mostrar sería algo así:

```
var win = window.location;

var webPath = win.pathname;

//Dividimos la string en un array
var splittedPath = webPath.split("/");

//El primer valor del array segun la estructura mostrada sería el del idioma
switch(splittedPath[0]) {
  case "en":
    //Mostrar pagina en ingles
    break;
  case "es":
    //Mostrar pagina en español
    break;
  default:
    //La opcion que quiera mostrar por defecto
    break;
}
```

El código funciona de la siguiente forma:

- En la primera línea obtenemos la instancia del navegador(`window.location`);
- En la segunda línea almacenamos en una variable llamada `webPath` el string correspondiente a la URL, en este caso sería: `/en/estapaginanoexiste`
- En la tercera línea dividimos el string separándolo según el caracter `/`, de tal manera que tendríamos un array cuyo valor 0 sería `en` y cuyo valor 1 sería `estapaginanoexiste`
- La cuarta línea es un switch en la que dependiendo del valor que tenga en la posicion `0` el array previamente mencionado muestre los elementos HTML en un idioma u otro, y que, si por el motivo que sea dicho valor no concuerda con ninguno incluido en el switch, pues se ejecuta las líneas posteriores a `default`.

**Nota: He omitido la parte del código en la que se maneja e incluyen elementos de html, si lo requiere, puede ver más informacion sobre como hacerlo [aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodes.asp)**

Comment: Persona mi ignorancia, pero mis conocimientos de javascript son nulos :S 

Entiendo más o menos la parte inferior del código que me proporcionas y que dentro de cada "case" faltaria añadir una línea de código que mostrase el div en cuestión ¿no?

Por otro lado, la idea es que por default se muestre en castellano. Siendo así, ¿que debería colocar en la última línea de código?

Comment: @JonathanCenteno He modificado la respuesta para que la pueda entender tanto usted como cualquier otro usuario del foro

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu explicación Álex. He probado con el enlace que me has facilitado y con otra opción que he buscado por mi cuenta, pero no consigo que ninguno funcione. No sé si lo estoy entendiendo mal o mi sintaxis es incorrecta. He añadido los códigos arriba.

Comment: En la opción 2(la que yo creo que es más correcta) te faltan `;` al final de algunas líneas de código. Te aparece algún error en la consola? Prueba a hacer debugging con tu IDE para ver cuales son los valores de las variables y ver por qué podría fallar? @JonathanCenteno